# Only one active new jframe

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have two forms : `f_main` and `f_recruitment`. I put a label in `f_main` with this code :

```
....
private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Recruitment Icon has been Clicked");
    new F_Recruitment().setVisible(true);
}                                    
 // to display f_recruitment
```

Question is how can I have just one active `f_recruitment` open?

Update:

Thanks, what I mean is, how can I prevent user from re-click `jLabel2` and another `f_recruitment` are open..? ( I let f_main form keep visible on purpose, while the new form `f_recruitment` is open)

Answer (score 2):

I agree completely with glowcoder (1+), that more information would be helpful and perhaps essential to competently answering this question, but another option is to use lazy initiation -- to create an F_Recruitment variable field that's null, and instantiate it in the listener if it's null, but regardless of whether it was initially null or not, at the bottom of the listener display the field.

```
public class MyClass {

  private F_Recruitment fRecruitment = null;

  // ... more code goes here

  private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Recruitment Icon has been Clicked"); 
    if (fRecruitment == null) {
      fRecruitment = new F_Recruitment();
    }
    fRecruitment.setVsible(true);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think there is enough information here to really answer your question.

You say you want just one active f_recruitment, but that implies there are more than one f_recruitment.

You could consider a toggle method:

```
private void toggleRecruitmentOn() {
    f_main.setVisible(false);
    f_recruitment.setVisible(true);
}

private void toggleMainOn() {
    f_recruitment.setVisible(false);
    f_main.setVisible(true);
}
```

I'll update this if more information gets posted about the issue at hand :)